# Does un-assigning a category group remove category assignments?

Tags: categories, category-group

I'm re-vamping a site, and we have updated the categories. At the moment I have two category groups, the old one and the new one. The old one will never be used again, but I'd prefer to keep the assignments, for posterity.

If I un-assign the old category group from the channels in question (so it doesn't show up in the editor), will those category assignments be lost?

Comment: I will go through and mark where appropriate, but sometimes there just isn't an answer.

Comment: No problem. If you found a different answer, always remember to post and accept it. Otherwise, if your problem is still unsolved, feel free to [add a bounty](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the function which runs when Channel Group Assignments are updated, I'm going to  say **no**, your categories will *not* be unassigned when removing a category group from a channel, so that's safe to do.

(*After* you backup your database of course, haha.)

**UPDATE:** as pointed out below, if you later edit these entries which have now-hidden categories assigned, those old category associations *will* be lost when the entry is updated. (This is because EE deletes all category associations and creates them all anew with the posted category data each time an entry is updated.)

Comment: Derek, that is at the moment you remove a cat-group. What will happen when you edit an entry and save it? won't it remove any non-selected categories (e.g. the old ones that are not showing?)

Comment: An excellent point - yes, if the old entries are edited with the old category group no longer assigned, the old category associations will be lost. Will revise answer!